# Trying to get Apache to serve webp instead of png/jpg (from /img folder of prestashop)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite, images, extension

First post here, so I hope I did it well.

I converted all png/jpg starting from my prestashop public_html folder to  webp, and added rewrite rules to the .htaccess in order to have the webp served instead of png/jpg.

I based my rewrites on the already existing prestashop rewrites.
Where I had:
`RewriteRule ^([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg [L]`
I ended up doing:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$1$2$3.webp [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.webp$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$1$2$3.webp [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
```

Which works: I got jpg URL serving webp images, so far so good (I know still need to implement

```
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
#RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.webp -f
```

and as well try to figure out if I should leave `[L]` or do `[L,T=image/webp]` or do `[T=image/webp,E=REQUEST_image]`, which is why I am reading apache related docs and crawling the web about rewrite related topics which is quiet huge indeed.

Ok, so back to the main topic, I saw that I was missing a webp rewrite for the images the prestashop stores in public_html/img folder.

Then I tried the following (and so other variants):

```
RewriteRule ^/img/(.+)\.jpe?g$ /img/$1.webp [L]
RewriteRule ^/img/(.+)\.png$ /img/$1.webp [L]
```

^--- NOT OK... still serving jpg/png type images from the img directory (double checked the MIME Type).


Note that:

1. Every time I changed .htaccess and tried a solution, I cleared the prestashop cache, just in case (despite knowing the .htaccess being read at every request).
2. webp images corresponding to jpg/png in img folder exist.
3. image file perms is correct in img folder and indeed in all stuff under public_html
4. In img folder in prestashop, there is another .htaccess, which restricts the type of files that can be served from this folder, and I added already webp, just in case someone should ask.

**UPDATE:** As requested by MrWhite, adding the .htaccess of the img folder

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_flag engine off
</IfModule>

# Apache 2.2
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    <Files ~ "(?i)^.*\.(webp|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|tiff|svg|pdf|mov|mpeg|mp4|avi|mpg|wma|flv|webm|ico)$">
        Allow from all
    </Files>
</IfModule>

# Apache 2.4
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
    <Files ~ "(?i)^.*\.(webp|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|tiff|svg|pdf|mov|mpeg|mp4|avi|mpg|wma|flv|webm|ico)$">
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</IfModule>
```

Please could you guys kindly help me here?

Comment: "In img folder in prestashop, there is another .htaccess" - Please edit your question to include the contents of this `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/img/(.+)\.jpe?g$ /img/$1.webp [L]
> RewriteRule ^/img/(.+)\.png$ /img/$1.webp [L]
> ```

In `.htaccess` files, the URL-path that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against, does not start with a slash. So the above directives will never match the requested URL, so won't do anything. In your earlier rules you are matching against a digit as the first character, not a slash.

For example, it should be:

```
RewriteRule ^img/(.+)\.jpe?g$ /img/$1.webp [L]
```

However...

> In img folder in prestashop, there is another `.htaccess`

Depending on the directives contained in `/img/.htaccess` file then these directives might be completely overriding the mod_rewrite directives in the parent `.htaccess` file. The mod_rewrite directives in the parent `.htaccess` might not even be getting processed.

**UPDATE:** Having now seen the `/img/.htaccess` file then it's OK - these directives will not over the directives in the parent `.htaccess` file with regards to rewriting the request to the `.webp` images.

Since these additional rules only apply to the `/img` subdirectory and you already have a `.htaccess` file in the `/img` subdirectory then you could write these rules in the `/img/.htaccess` file instead (slight adjustment required). For example:

```
# /img/.htaccess

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.jpe?g$ $1.webp [L]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the URL-path *relative* to the directory that contains the `.htaccess` file. So, in this case, it does not match against the `/img` subdirectory.

---

To complete the rule and incorporate the other conditions you've mentioned you can do the following. Now back in the root `.htaccess` file:

```
# /.htaccess

# Rewrite image request to ".webp" if supported and exists
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.webp -f
RewriteRule ^(img/.+)\.(jpe?g|png)$ $1.webp [L,T=image/webp]
```

If the corresponding `.webp` image is guaranteed to exist then you don't necessarily need the filesystem check (the second condition).

(I'm not sure why you would need `E=REQUEST_image`?)

And if using the `.htaccess` file in the `/img` subdirectory:

```
# /img/.htaccess

# Rewrite image request to ".webp" if supported and exists
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/img/$1.webp -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(jpe?g|png)$ $1.webp [L,T=image/webp]
```

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$1$2$3.webp [L]
> RewriteRule ^([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.webp$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$1$2$3.webp [L]
> RewriteRule ^([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
> ```

The 3rd rule isn't doing anything and should be removed. And the first two rules can be easily combined using regex alternation on the file extension. eg. `(jpg|webp)`.

Comment: It works (I choosed the "in img/" .htaccess approach you proposed).
Thanks a lot to you for the proposed solutions and comprehensive explainations! 
And yes before I got reply, in the meantime I did try the regex in this web [link](https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/) and found that I had to remove the heading slash to get a match.
Still thanks to you I got this and more very clear now.

Comment: Regarding your comment about the "3rd line":

This was present in the default .htaccess as generated by prestashop, and I think it was used in order to get "friendly url".

Comment: @Totoro Ok, quite possibly. However, in your "new" trio of rules, your first rule will rewrite the `.jpg` request to `.webp` first, so the 3rd is never processed. If, however, you add the mentioned _conditions_ to the first rule then the 3rd rule would have purpose as an "else" clause when (if) the first rule should fail.

Comment: Thanks again @MrWhite for the comprehensive explaination (again) :) !